# What are the uses of the Golden Apple?

Tags: chrono-ark

In the game **'Chrono Ark'**, one of the obtainable items is the 'golden apple', obtainable from the hidden secret rooms in levels 2 to 5, which heals a party member for 25 health, ignoring the healing gauge penalty. The golden apple cannot heal a fainted party member.

The game hints at other uses of the golden apple. What are these uses? Is there some relevant strategy to it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the apple is valuable in combat as an 'oh no' button.
I have found 3 uses so far aside from the obvious one, which all give permanent benefits. That means using it in combat is typically a 'last resort'. You would want to use the healing potions, which do the same thing worse (heal 12 instead of 25 hp), first.

1. **Scroll of Midas**

If you have a Scroll of Midas, you can use it on a Golden Apple to gain money. Unfortunately the reward is rather small at only 300 coins. For comparison, a regular purple item rewards you with 1,800 coins. I don't recommend ever doing this.

2. **Enchant at a library**

Attempting to enchant a regular consumable at a library will simply fail; the library won't accept the item. The golden apple, however, if enchanted is consumed and produces one of Lucy's rare skills.

These are typically highly valuable *swift* skills that tend to strictly increase the power of the deck, with more powerful ones unlockable at the Research center with Time Shade.

Because you are usually restricted to 1 such skill, having an additional one is very valuable. This is my preferred use of the apple.

3. **Use at the smithy**

The Golden apple can be used at a smithy in place of a regular item as a 'joker'. It is most valuable in place of a purple item, to create a maximum-quality orange item from another purple item.

This is situationally how I use my apple, as there are some purple items that aren't very valuable. This can happen if:

3a. I have many items that do the same thing; superfluous items.

For example: As each character has only 2 slots, and there is typically one 'healing' character, the third healing item is superfluous.

3b. There's a purple item I'd rather not use.

A good example is Vadzerald, especially early game. The cost of gradually making my cards unplayable is not worth the reward of 20% increased power or so.

### Strategy summary

If you obtain an apple, try to save it. Check if you have useless purple items (or 2 useless blue items). If so, use it at the smithy as a purple item. Otherwise, use it at the library to gain a valuable support skill. If neither is available to you and you're already in stage 5, just use it as a healing potion.